# Non standard evaluation in dplyr: how do you indirect a function's multiple arguments?

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I'm trying to write a function that can pass either one or more arguments as variables to dplyr functions. I'd like to understand how to do it generally. [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) doesn't seem to cover the issue and some of the more autoritative documentation that you can find with Google or in vignettes (ie `` ?`!!!` ``) seems to be outdated. Below I provide an example of what I'm trying to get and where I fail:

```
df <- as_tibble(mtcars)


df %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)) #This is the result I want from a function


testfunc <- function(variables) {
  df %>% group_by({{variables}}) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

testfunc(cyl)                                             #It works for a single variable

testfunc(cyl, gear)                                       #It fails for multiple variables

testfunc2 <- function(variables) {                        #Second attempt
  variables <- enquos(variables)
  df %>% group_by(!!variables) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

testfunc2(cyl, gear)                                       #Unused argument error
testfunc2(c(cyl, gear))                                    #Doesn't work
testfunc2(c("cyl", "gear"))                                #Doesn't work
```

How do you solve this problem in a general way?

Thanks!!

Comment: The link you provided does cover this. Use `testfunc <- function(...) {df %>% group_by(...) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))}`. But you need to decide how you are passing in variable. You can't expect both character values and symbols to work the same. You can't pass character values to `group_by` directly.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I missed it and it was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a *arg* for the *data.frame* and add the `...` for others variables to *group by*

```
testfunc <- function(df,...) {
  df %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}
testfunc(mtcars,cyl,gear)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in detail in "Advanced R" written by Hadley Wickham (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/ / https://amzn.to/2WoabjB) e.g. Chapters 6, 19, 20:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- as_tibble(mtcars)
df %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  gear   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     3  21.5
#> 2     4     4  26.9
#> 3     4     5  28.2
#> 4     6     3  19.8
#> 5     6     4  19.8
#> 6     6     5  19.7
#> 7     8     3  15.0
#> 8     8     5  15.4

testfunc <- function(variables) {
  df %>% group_by({{variables}}) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

testfunc(cyl)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  26.7
#> 2     6  19.7
#> 3     8  15.1
testfunc(cyl, gear)
#> Error in testfunc(cyl, gear): unused argument (gear)

# https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html?q=...#fun-dot-dot-dot
testfunc2 <- function(variables, ...) {                        #Second attempt
  variables <- enquos(variables, ...)
  df %>% group_by(!!!variables) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
}

testfunc2(cyl, gear)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl  gear   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     3  21.5
#> 2     4     4  26.9
#> 3     4     5  28.2
#> 4     6     3  19.8
#> 5     6     4  19.8
#> 6     6     5  19.7
#> 7     8     3  15.0
#> 8     8     5  15.4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>